# ListIterator.remove is throwing IlegalStateExcpetion

Tags: java

*consider below two samples*

```
    public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(3);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(1);
        ListIterator<Integer> listIterator = list.listIterator();
        int i =0;
        while(listIterator.hasNext()){
            listIterator.next();
            listIterator.add(5);
            listIterator.remove();

        }

    }
}
```

*where remove method Throws IllegalStateException  and in below if we call set before remove is not throwing any expception*

```
  public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(3);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(1);
        ListIterator<Integer> listIterator = list.listIterator();
        int i =0;
        while(listIterator.hasNext()){
            listIterator.next();
            listIterator.set(5);
            listIterator.remove();

        }

    }
}
```

can some explain me...

Comment: your two samples are identical

Comment: your two samples are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you didn't bother to read the apidocs for the remove
method.

> void remove()
>
> Removes from the list the last element that was returned by next() or 
>   previous() (optional operation). This call can only be made once per
>   call to next or previous. It can be made only if add(E) has not been
>   called after the last call to next or previous.
>
> Specified by:
>       remove in interface Iterator Throws:
>
> ```
> UnsupportedOperationException - if the remove operation is not supported by this list iterator
> IllegalStateException - if neither next nor previous have been called, or remove or add have been called after the last call to next or previous
> ```

It says that it will throw IllegalStateException on remove if you haven't called next or previous, or the remove or add methods have been called.

Comment: I have been through apidocs, my question was what made them to throw exception for add and what did not made them not to throw exception, because both are chaging value returned by next()

Comment: First of all, you're asking why the implementers chose to implement the spec in this particular way, which is not a question I can answer.  I can, however, take a guess.  I will start out by pointing out that your statement above is actually incorrect.

The call to set() sets the value at the current position of the iterator.  The call to add() adds a new element into the list.  My question to you then, is where does it add the new item?  The spec is strangely silent here.  Does it add it after the current position?  Before?  At the front or end of the list?  That is undefined behavior.

Comment: To take this to the next step, I ask you, where is the pointer after the add operation?  The spec also has nothing to say on this topic.  When I call next(), will it move to the thing I just added?  Or the thing that was after the current position before I added things to the list?  Again, undefined behavior.  Rather than make something up, they chose to throw an exception instead.

Comment: add insterts  the specified element into the list (optional operation).
     * The element is inserted immediately before the element that
     * would be returned by {@link #next}
i.e the above element is added between the last value returned by next() and value that is going to returned by after calling next()

Comment: That may be what happens in practice.  It is not specified in the documented interface, therefore it may change at any time with a future update, therefore it is undefined.  I'm not sure what else I can say at this point...